# Hiding the "Loading..." indicator when implementing a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created display using `Fragments`, both of which is being populated with data pulled from the internet. While the code itself works as expected without any issues, one of a Fragments (implemented as `ListFragment`) displays an indeterminant progress indicator within the fragment, which is skewed off to the side. I wish to remove the indicator and use a different `ProgressDialog` I implemented as the indicator instead.

Doing some research, I have discovered the function `setListShownNoAnimation()` (documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListShownNoAnimation(boolean))) in the `ListFragment` class, but the following attempts didn't work:

- Calling setListShownNoAnimation() in the fragment's `onActivityCreated()`
- Calling it in the parent activity's `onCreate`
- Calling it in the fragment's `onCreateView()` (this caused an `IllegalStateException`)

How can I remove the fragment's progress indicator?

Comment: tryed using setListShown(true)?

Comment: @Warpzit: From what the Android API indicates, `setListShown(true)` will display the ListView (which may or may not have been initialized and set). Additionally, it doesn't seem disable the loading indicator, which the `setListShownNoAnimation()` does seem to do.

Comment: was just a guess :) sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The right way to do this is to call:

```
setListShown(true);
```

when you need the ProgressBar to be hidden and show the ListView. Call this when you are finished getting the data in the background and are ready to show the list.

Comment: That does seem like the right way since if you pass the method false, it apparently should show a loading progress indicator to the user which is nice. the problem is, when i use this method in my ListFragment, i get IllegalStateException, can't be used with a custom content view. What gives?

Comment: You are correct. That should generally be the right way to call it. My project was done a bit differently though, which required a different approach. I'm marking your answer is the accepted answer still. :)

Comment: This should be called in onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround may not be the best method to solve this, but it works nicely:

What I did was first make the Fragment not display at all when I declared it in the layout.xml file:

```
<fragment class="com.example.MyListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/frag_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Then after the data has been downloaded and processed, I would then display the Fragment using a FragmentTransaction:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.show(frag);
ft.commit();
```

If there is a better way to resolve this issue, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Well if the visibility is gone you should change it programaticly to visible, `setVisivility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    if(isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}
```

But you have to `setListShown(false)` where you set the `ListAdapter`. This works fine.