# ListFragment with FragmentActivity unable to hide progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have a two listfragment fragmentactivity. The two listfragment load data with AsyncTask. For a reason unknown to me, in loading data ListFragment one ProgressBar shown. This progressBar I want to remove, and then I want to add a custom progressbar.
I have searched countless issues to stackoverflow and more sites but can not find any solution. 
Thanks in advance.

My code:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  


        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ExamplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);


    }//fin oncreate

    public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
            public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            //Modificacion
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(position){
            case 0:
            fragment = new RlsFragment();
            break;
            case 1:
            fragment = new ArtFragment();
            break;
            }   
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }
    }//fin examplepageAdapter
}
```

One ListFragment

```
public class RlsFragment extends ListFragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new CreateArrayListTaskRls().execute();

    }

    private class CreateArrayListTaskRls extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {     


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {       

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String...strings)
        {           

            loadDataJsonRls();
            int paso_i = 1;
            getDataSD();            
            return paso_i;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer paso_j) {
            if(getActivity()!=null){            
                adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), array_adpn,array_pl,array_url);                
                setListAdapter(adapter);    
            }
        }


    }//fin createArraylistTask
}fin class
```

Comment: I did not seek enough but eventually I found it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257561/hiding-the-loading-indicator-when-implementing-a-listfragment